# Run javascript code within an open browser tab's context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I'm trying to improve my dev-loop.

In order to do this, I'm trying to find a way to execute javascript code (Mainly react components) as if they were being executed within an open browser tab. Almost as if they were being executed from the dev tools console window.

The idea is to try and test my components in the environment within which they will be used without having to package - deploy - setup on the final environment every single time.

Doing this will give the components access to data from API calls without having to mock or re-authenticate to the service, and will also expose them to global variables / tools available on the window object of the page in the environment where the code is supposed to be executed.

Is there some magic that makes this possible?

I'm not sure if I'm making sense or doing a good job of conveying my ask clearly. Please do let me know if you would like me to clarify further!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Storybook what you're looking for? https://storybook.js.org/